# RMSD from a set of points R

Tags: r, coordinates, points

Hello I need to calculate the RMSD of two sets of point with x,y,z coordinate.I was trying with something founded online but it doesn't work. How can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example and a solution of your problem :

conf_a <- list(atom_i=c(-34, 68,127), atom_j=c(-56, 22,-79))

conf_b <- list(atom_i=c(-35,67,122), atom_j=c(-55, 23,-76))

rmsd <- c()

for(n_atom in seq(1, length(conf_a)){

```
rmsd <- c(rmsd, sqrt(sum(abs(conf_a[[n_atom]]-conf_b[[n_atom]])**2)/length(conf_a)))
```

}